# Cartoon show about a main character girl with short red hair, a blond guy, a teacher, some girl with maybe blue hair and a sceptre and power gauntlets

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

So I don’t remember much but I do know it was a school setting.
These kids, I remember the main girl having short red hair, another guy with blond hair and this teacher that leads them through these ruins under their school.
The girl had a flying fluffy pink pet thing and the kids wear these gauntlet things around their forearms that shoot out a power beam.
The uniform I’m pretty sure is light brown and white.
There’s another blue haired girl with a sceptre who lives in the dorms at the school.
But that’s all I can remember, the closest I got to it is Oban Star Racers but it’s not that.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to SFF.SE! When did you watch this cartoon? Where was it broadcasted? Can you give details on the animation style (japanese-like, western-like)?

Comment: @Orlahm It was a mix of both, similar to something like Code Lyoko or Oban Star Racers, not quite anime but also not just a western cartoon. I watched it roughly around 2013-2014, on a cartoon channel from my home country and I’ve tried checking their broadcast list and haven’t been able to find it through that. Also thank you for responding:))